# In docker environment, I can't execute "make" command with any options, they all show me warnings resemble " Unknown option: -v"

Tags: android, docker, makefile

When I enter docker environment, I try to execute `make -v` or `make -C` and any other options, it shows me warnings `Unknow option:-v` or `Unknow option:-C`.

Comment: Try adding `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential` to your Dockerfile. Though you're more likely looking for a multi-stage build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Obsidian, but my build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).

Comment: _Which_ Docker environment? Using which entry point? We'd really need a Dockerfile and a `docker run` command that reproduce the problem before anyone but you could develop, test, _or benefit from_ an answer; with most Dockerfiles, running `make` through the ENTRYPOINT is the same as running it from bash; until we know what's special about the specific Dockerfile that causes this problem for you we can't edit this question to narrow it to be more easily found by people with the specific problem mechanism the answer describes how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself, just enter bash env, you can perform "make" normally.